# How do I deserialize a json representation of list of lists using JavaScript Overlay?

Tags: javascript, json, list, gwt, deserialization

I have my expansive server side java objects that implement these simplified interfaces:

```
interface Vector {
  public double getX();
  public double getY();
}

interface Geometry {
  public List<Vector> getShell();//can get big
  public List<List<Vector>> getHoles();
}

interface Feature {
  public String getID();
  public List<Geometry> getGeometry();
}
```

I construct a list of features that I convert to json using gson lib. The result looks like this, except that it's a lot bigger.

> [{"i":"304","g":[{"s":[{"x":-3169996.4370428286,"y":1.1231962684336938E7},{"x":-3287403.71248886,"y":1.1192826925854929E7},{"x":-2935181.88615077,"y":1.115369116737292E7}....

I am able to parse the json into a JsArray where JsFeature is a javascriptobject that implements the feature interface.

How do I get the rest of the data without having to parse through my json vector by vector. Ideally, I would like to have a way to convert the List into JsList where JsGeometry is a JavascriptObject class implementing Geometry, which would include a List and so on and so forth..

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `List` class that delegates everything to an underlying `JsArray`, but that's not as easy as it sounds (and why it's not built-in GWT).

I'd rather recommend using [AutoBean](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean):

```
interface Factory extends AutoBeanFactory {
   AutoBean<Feature> feature();
}

Factory factory = GWT.create(Factory.class);

Feature feature = AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, Feature.class, jsonString).as();
```

The runtime overhead is minimal, almost the same as a `List` wrapping a `JsArray` but you don't have to code anything to make it work.

Also note you could even use AutoBean on the server-side instead of GSON.

Comment: would I be able to get the underlying List<Geometry> just by `AutoBean`ing the feature class??

Comment: Absolutely! You don't have to change anything to your interfaces, just use the AutoBeanFactory and AutoBeanCodex and you're done.